# Retrieving a list of records from a file and add them to a variable list

Tags: list, shell, file

I want to:

1. Provide a list of certain folders (starting with MG) in a certain path and write this list into a .txt file

   ```
   ls | grep MG*.* > tempfile.txt
   ```

   File.txt contents should be:

   ```
   MG-x###1 
   MG-x###2 
   MG-x###3
   ```
2. Read the .txt file and take the name of the folders and make them items as part of a list

   ```
   listvariables="MG-x###1 MG-x###2 MG-x###3"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve 2. would be to use `awk` to join everything together.

```
cat tempfile.txt | awk '{printf $1" "}'
```

So in your bash script you will have something like this:

```bash
listvariables=$(cat tempfile.txt | awk '{printf $1" "}')
```

Answer (score 0):

In a shell that supports arrays (bash, zsh, ksh), use an array: `files=(MG*.*)`.

If your shell doesn't support arrays, you can still use glob expansion: `list=$(echo MG*.*)` or `list=$(printf '%s\n' MG*.*)` etc.

If the reason you want a list is to loop over it, again use glob expansion:

```
for i in MG*.*; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

To target directories only, use `MG*.*/`.

Comment: that worked as well and makes the code more robust I believe! Many thanks!